# Mexican Train Dominoes. Can you start the «Mexican Train» as part of your first move?

Tags: dominoes

**The rule**
When you play your first move as a series of dominoes ending in a double domino, and you don't have one of the dominoes required to «satisfy» the double, you are required to play another domino on any available train.

**The question**
Can the other domino you play start the «Mexican Train»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**,

There is nothing in the rules that make starting the Mexican train an exception, and playing on the Mexican Train (starting or otherwise) is a valid play after playing a double.